# Access asp.net mvc controller ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, compiler-errors, asp.net-mvc-routing

i want to access action result in controller(my controlelr is HotelController action is Index)

(`http://localhost:9001/Hotel/Index`) it gives below error

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Hotel/Index

Hotel controller

```
public class HotelController : Base.BoxyController
    {
        protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

            ViewBag.Title = "SonDakka - Otel";
        }

        public ActionResult Index(string culture)
        {
```

.........

BoxyController

```
 public class BoxyController : MainController
    {
        protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
```

..........

MainController

```
  public class MainController : SiteController
    {
        protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
```

......

SiteController

```
  [ExitHttpsIfNotRequired]
    public class SiteController : Controller
    {
        public Account Me { get; set; }

        protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
```

.......

and this is my global.asax

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Tourism.Data;
using Tourism.Data.Mvc.Authorization;
using Tourism.Data.Mvc.Routing;

namespace Tourism
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(TourismContext db, RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            var cultures = db.Cultures.Select(c => c.Code).ToArray();

            routes.MapRoute
                (
                    "Ajax",
                    "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    new { id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                    new { culture = new ArrayRouteConstraint(true, cultures), controller = new ArrayRouteConstraint(true, "Ajax") }
                ).RouteHandler = new GlobalizedRouteHandler();

            routes.Add
                (
                    "Page",
                    new GlobalizedPageRoute
                        (
                            "{culture}/{path}",
                            null,
                            new RouteValueDictionary { { "culture", new ArrayRouteConstraint(true, cultures) } },
                            new GlobalizedRouteHandler()
                        )
                );

            routes.Add
                (
                    "Route",
                    new GlobalizedRoute
                        (
                            "{culture}/{path}/{slug}/{id}",
                            new RouteValueDictionary { { "culture", UrlParameter.Optional }, { "path", UrlParameter.Optional }, { "slug", UrlParameter.Optional }, { "id", UrlParameter.Optional } }, 
                            new RouteValueDictionary { { "culture", new ArrayRouteConstraint(false, cultures) } },
                            new GlobalizedRouteHandler()
                        )
                );
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<TourismContext>(null);

            using (var db = new TourismContext())
            {
                #if !DEBUG

                if (!db.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true))
                {
                    System.Web.HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();

                    throw new Exception("Veritabanı değişikliği tespit edildi.");
                }

                #endif

                AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

                RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

                RegisterRoutes(db, RouteTable.Routes);
            }
        }

        protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest()
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Context.User = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal =
                    new AuthorizationPrincipal(Context.User.Identity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Requested URL: /Hotel/Thanks" - that is part of the error? If yes then do you have a method called "Thanks"?

Comment: i should update question... i try to access index it gives error than i try for thanks it still give some error... http://localhost:9001/Hotel/Index

Comment: Can you post your route config? Please edit your post and include it.

Comment: i post global.asax and include code... thanks von v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the route config you posted, your URL should be with `culture`, for example:

```
http://localhost:9001/en/Hotel/Index
```

Notice the **`en`** before `Hotel`. It could be any value that is valid in your database.

Answer (score 3):

Because this is due to Razor engine unable to find Thanks action in Hotel controller. You need to make a Thanks action with in Hotel controller like this:

```
public class HotelController : Base.BoxyController
{

 public ActionResult Thanks(string culture)
 {
    return View();
 }

}
```

And also make sure to create a view in Hotel folder with your html code.

Comment: i update question...i edited my question mistake...my HotelController has thanks and Index action...

Comment: http://localhost:9001/Hotel/Index  i call this and this give error....and HotelController has Index action result.....  public ActionResult Index(string culture)....